# Function setting enable to False only works on some buttons?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qpushbutton

I am working on setting up a controls dashboard for operators. whenever a heartbeat stops incrementing, after 5 seconds, the LED changes to red. This also enables the acknowledge buttons. When I click them, the LED chages to yellow and I would like to disable the button again. The issue is that  it only works for some of the buttons in my code for some reason. any idea why that might be? It only works for the buttons on the left side and not the right side. I am sure that the error is happening at "heartbeats[string][5].setEnabled(False)"

```
def ack_thread(string):
    ack = threading.Thread(target=acknowledge, args=(string,))
    ack.start()

def acknowledge(string):
    global heartbeats
    rowcount = ui.tableWidget.rowCount()
    for x in range(0, rowcount, 1):
        if ui.tableWidget.item(x,0).text() == string:
            print(ui.tableWidget.item(x,0).text())
            if ui.tableWidget.item(x,4).text() == 'False':
                ui.tableWidget.setItem(x, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("True"))
                ui.tableWidget.viewport().update()
    heartbeats[string][3].setPixmap(ui.yellowled)
    print(heartbeats[string][5])
    # heartbeats[string][5].setEnabled(True)
    heartbeats[string][5].setEnabled(False)

def gettime():
    import datetime
    currentDT = datetime.datetime.now()
    return currentDT.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

def alarm_handler(source):
    rowPosition = ui.tableWidget.rowCount()
    ui.tableWidget.insertRow(rowPosition)
    ui.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 0, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(source))
    ui.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 1, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("text1"))
    ui.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 2, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("text2"))
    ui.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 3, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(gettime()))
    ui.tableWidget.setItem(rowPosition, 4, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem("False"))

def heartbeat():
    import mhs2
    from time import sleep
    global heartbeats
    mhs2.DB_CONFIG['host'] = '192.168.1.79'
    # old value, new value, number of failures, LED object, checkbutton object, Acknowledge object,acknowledged
    heartbeats = {
        'pd1_hb': [0, 0, 0, ui.label_26, ui.checkBox_7, ui.pushButton_11, True],
        'pd9_hb': [0, 0, 0, ui.label_20, ui.checkBox_12, ui.pushButton_13, True],
        'pd11_hb': [0, 0, 0, ui.label_21, ui.checkBox_11, ui.pushButton_12, True],
        'pd13_hb': [0, 0, 0, ui.label_22, ui.checkBox_13, ui.pushButton_2, True],
        'irr1_hb': [0, 0, 0, ui.label_25, ui.checkBox_8, ui.pushButton_5, True],
        'irr2_hb': [0, 0, 0, ui.label_24, ui.checkBox_9, ui.pushButton_4, True],
        'irr5_hb': [0, 0, 0, ui.label_23, ui.checkBox_10, ui.pushButton_3, True],
        'kyledata_hb': [0, 0, 0, ui.label_14, ui.checkBox, ui.pushButton, True],
        'standata_hb': [0, 0, 0, ui.label_19, ui.checkBox_3, ui.pushButton_10, True],
        'kennydata_hb': [0, 0, 0, ui.label_18, ui.checkBox_4, ui.pushButton_9, True],
        'cartmandata_hb': [0, 0, 0, ui.label_17, ui.checkBox_6, ui.pushButton_8, True],
        'chefdata_hb': [0, 0, 0, ui.label_16, ui.checkBox_5, ui.pushButton_6, True],
        'buttarsdata_hb':  [0, 0, 0, ui.label_15, ui.checkBox_2, ui.pushButton_7, True]
    }

    for item in heartbeats:
        heartbeats[item][3].setPixmap(ui.offled)
    query = "SELECT * FROM Heartbeat"
    enable = mhs2.exec_query(query)
    for row in enable:
        if row['enable'] == 1:
            heartbeats[row['parameter']][4].setChecked(True)
        else:
            heartbeats[row['parameter']][4].setChecked(False)
    while 1:
        command = "SELECT * FROM Heartbeat"
        hb = mhs2.exec_query(command)
        for row in hb:
            if heartbeats[row['parameter']][4].isChecked():
                heartbeats[row['parameter']][1] = row['value']
                if heartbeats[row['parameter']][1] != heartbeats[row['parameter']][0]:
                    heartbeats[row['parameter']][2] = 0
                    heartbeats[row['parameter']][3].setPixmap(ui.greenled)
                    heartbeats[row['parameter']][6] = True
                else:
                    heartbeats[row['parameter']][2] += 1
                if heartbeats[row['parameter']][2] > 5 and heartbeats[row['parameter']][6]:
                    heartbeats[row['parameter']][3].setPixmap(ui.redled)
                    heartbeats[row['parameter']][5].setEnabled(True)
                    heartbeats[row['parameter']][6] = False
                    alarm = threading.Thread(target=alarm_handler,args=(row['parameter'],))
                    alarm.start()
                heartbeats[row['parameter']][0] = heartbeats[row['parameter']][1]
            else:
                heartbeats[row['parameter']][3].setPixmap(ui.offled)

        sleep(1)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Dialog = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Dialog()
    ui.setupUi(Dialog)
    Dialog.show()
    hb = threading.Thread(target=heartbeat)
    hb.start()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing and incomplete, it's really hard to understand what is going on if you don't provide us a [minimal, and *actually* reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Anyway, you should *never* access QWidgets from any thread but the main Qt thread (see the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/threads-qobject.html), and I really think that that's the issue in this case. Try using QThreads and signal/slots to access and interact with the GUI.

Comment: The character limit kept me from posting the graphical portions, and my reputation isn't high enough to post pictures. Thanks for the advice, I will look into this and see if that is the issue. Would a mutex possibly protect from this issue? The main issue is that using some of the buttons crashes the program but the others work perfectly even though they are setup identically.

Comment: Using a mutex (as in lock) won't solve the threading issue. GUI elements should *always* be accessed (especially when changing properties and/or behavior) from the main Qt loop thread; using signals and slots prevents this kind of issues, as long as you use QThreads instead of python threads, since Qt can "understand" on which thread the operation will eventually occur: if the thread of the object that emits the signal is on a different one than the object receiving it (the slot), it will be executed in the latter. This will avoid any kind of issue, possibly including those crashes you faced.